# How sharp are sea berry thorns?

Tags: berries, thorns

I've read that sea buckthorn needles are lethal, so I was wondering how sharp they are. Are they like sewing needles, or like a pen point?
[image]

Comment: link for lethality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the sharpness of the thorns depends on the cultivar

> Normally sea buckthorn has thorns surrounding the berries which also vary in density, shape, size and sharpness. In Russia, Germany and Mongolia, thornless or near thornless cultivars have been bred.

https://www.statpub.com/index.php/gab/article/54228

This is [Harvest Moon](http://vegetolab.com/Seabuckthorn_an.html), a largely thornless variety

[image: thornless cultivar]

Comment: What about the other ones, because I live in the US, not CA?